# How can I debug a nerd font not working on Windows + Neovim?

Tags: neovim, font, astronvim, windows

I am on Windows using AstroNvim.

On other machines and installs, merely installing my nerd font is enough to make it work but this time and installation, all icons stay blank.

What steps can I take to debug this?

Comment: What is your run the command: `:set guifont=*`. Do you get the font dialog? Can you select the Nerd font you have installed? What if you select that font, are the "blank" icon getting replaced?

Comment: The output of your command is blank

Comment: Don't you get the Font dialog? Are you using nvim.exe or nvim-qt.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## nvim.exe

If you run the console version of Neovim (`nvim.exe`) then the font used is the font of the console you are using (e.g. `cmd.exe`)

To control the font you have to configure it in your console. Each console will have it own way.

### cmd.exe

For `cmd.exe` use the context menu of the window bar:

[image]

Select the Font tab a choose your font:

[image]

### terminal

For `terminal` use the context menu of the window bar:

[image]

Go to Default:

[image]

Select Appearance:

[image]

Select Font Face:

[image]

## nvim-qt.exe

If you run the GUI version of Neovim (`nvim-qt.exe`) I would run the following Neovim command:

```
:set guifont=*
```

It should bring the Font dialog:

[image: Font Dialog]

You should be able to pick the Nerd font you have installed (otherwise the problem is in the installation of the font)

If you select the font and hit OK the "blank" icons should be replaced by nice looking characters.

If it works you can copy the result of the following Neovim command into your `init.vim`

```
:set guifont?
```

`init.vim`:

```
set guifont=Cousine\ Nerd\ Font Mono:h9
```

Remark you have to escape the white space with backslash (`\`)

On AstroVim you have to modify `~\nvim\lua\astrovim\options.lua` and add:

```lua
local options = astronvim.user_opts("options", {
  opt = {
    breakindent = true, -- Wrap indent to match  line start
    clipboard = "unnamedplus", -- Connection to the system clipboard
    -- ...
    -- Addition: >>
    guifont = "Cousine Nerd Font Mono:h9",
    -- Addition: <<
  },
```

Comment: I did your second solution and it did nothing. I copy-pasted the name of the font as per MS Word.

Comment: The name of the font is often not exactly the word in MS-Word. That is why `set guifont=*` is so useful ;-)

Comment: This command does nothing by me.

Comment: Are you using `nvim.exe` or `nvim-qt.exe`?

Comment: nvim.exe 

Comment: Then the font is controlled by the console that you are using. Which version of the console are you using: `cmd.exe`, `conemu.exe` [conemu](https://conemu.github.io/), ...?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productid/9N0DX20HK701?ocid=pdpshare this one. I wonder how to quickly access the program files of this app and maybe check the process name by the way.

Comment: I'll tell you how to do but I suppose the instruction will look similar to the one of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148671/discussion-between-samuelnihoul-and-vivian-de-smedt).